# C++: is conditional inheritance possible

Tags: c++, inheritance, arduino

I'm working on a micro-processor(Arduino) project. My library `Foo` is inherited from a existing library `Basic`. Later I extended the functionalities of `Basic`, into another class `Advanced`. However, `Advanced` stretches the hardware harder, making one of the already made demos unusable.

What I'm thinking about is as following:

```
class Foo:
#ifndef USE_BASIC
public Advanced
#else
public Basic
#endif
{
...
}
```

And put `#define USE_BASIC` in my demo code:

```
#define USE_BASIC
#include <Foo.h>
```

However Foo is not inheriting from Basic. Am I doing it wrong here? Or if there're alternatives to solve this problem?

Comment: You'll have to define `USE_BASIC` in every translation unit (.cpp + included headers) that includes `Foo.h`, before the `#include <Foo.h>` directive. Consider either using a compiler switch (that declares `USE_BASIC` automatically in every translation unit) or put the `#define` in the header.

Comment: @Named I don't agree. Headers are nothing special, the OP shows the example defining `USE_BASIC` before including the header. Compiler is run on the cpp, therefore the preprocessor sees the define first _then_ includes the header (in the OP's example).

Comment: I can't understand the -1.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A much more clean solution would be using template : let the compiler choose the base class depending on a template argument.

Here is one example:

```
 #include <type_traits> //for std::conditional


 //here you go with your own class
 template<bool UseAdvanced>
 class Foo : public std::conditional<UseAdvanced, Advanced, Basic>::type
 {
      //your code
 };
```

And here is how you would be using this class:

```
Foo<true>   fooWithAdvanced; //it uses Advanced as base class
Foo<false>  fooWithBasic;    //it uses Basic as base class!
```

Well that is one way to do that. But there are better ways. In particular, I would design the class template in the following way, in which the template argument would act as *base* class. This would be more flexible design.

```
 template<typename Base>
 class Foo : public Base
 {
      //your code
 };
```

So you can use `Basic`, `Advanced` or *any other class as base class*, as long as it supports the functionalities as required by `Foo` and its usage:

```
 Foo<Advanced>  fooWithAdvanced;
 Foo<Basic>     fooWithBasic;
 Foo<OtherBase> fooWithOtherBase;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks! It's quite good to know about these methods, may not fit my case though, not sure if adding templates into microprocessors will do it more good or evil...

Comment: @XunYang: What "microprocessors" are you talking about? Did you mean preprocessor? If yes, then you don't need to use preprocessor with templates.

Comment: No, it's on Arduino, so this is kind of an embedded system

Comment: @XunYang: I don't think template would cause any issue in Arduino, because once a class template is instantiated, it becomes just like any other ordinary class.

Comment: templates is not a default language feature for the Arduino compiler, so I'll need to bring in another 3rd-part library to use templates, which will take more storage space that's already at its limits... May worth a try though, for the next project :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic configuration problem that library vendors face constantly. For small projects, just `#define` `USE_BASIC`, when appropriate, in the `foo.h` header. For larger projects with lots of configuration options you might want to go to a configuration file that gets `#include`d in every library header and define appropriate things there. In that case, I'd do all of the selection in the configuration header:

```
// uncomment to use `Basic` throughout:
// #define USE_BASIC
#ifdef USE_BASIC
typedef Basic FooBase;
#else
typedef Advanced FooBase;
#endif
```

Comment: I'm sure you meant `typedef Basic FooBase;` **not** `typedef FooBase Basic;` Same with the other typedef.

Comment: @Nawaz - yup, thanks. Don't know how I did something that silly. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to avoid inheritance and use patterns like [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) that offer much more flexibility. So you can change the behaviour of Foo during runtime from `Basic` to `Advanced`.

Comment: That might not be possible if memory is limited or indirections hit performance too much.

Answer (score 1):

Some people suggested the pattern strategy. 
If your choice is during compile-time, you should better use Policy-based design: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design

This is roughly the same design as yours, but you use templates:

```
template <class Base> class YourClass : public base {
    ...
};
```

At use:

```
#ifdef BASIC
typedef YourFinalClass Yourclass<Basic>;
#else
typedef YourFinalClass Yourclass<Advanced>;
#endif
```