# How to make a class template copy/move constructible/assignable with `std::enable_if_t`

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++17

## Context

I'm writing a class template with three parameters so that it is copy/move constructible, copy/move assignable. The class has two template parameters: (1) a type named `tree_t` and (2) an enumeration value

```
enum class bounding_t { bound, unbound };
```

If (2) is `bounding_t::bound` then the class needs to have a member `const tree_t&`; when (2) is `bounding_t::unbound`, the class should not have it. For this I used [conditional inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16359147/12075306):

```
template <typename tree_t, bounding_t bound>
using base_impl =
    std::conditional_t<is_collection_bound<bound>,
                       base_tree<tree_t>,
                       base<tree_t>>;

template <typename tree_t, bounding_t bound>
class arrangement_collection : public base_impl<tree_t, bound> { }
```

The constructors use `std::enable_if_t` to construct the parent class appropriately.

## Attempts at solving

I tried several things to make the class copy/move assignable and copy/move constructible (I'm not sure I can list all of them without exceeding body size limit), but I failed to make it so that none of the assertions fail, and so that the compiler does not issue any warnings. The MWE below makes four assertions fail, all involving `bounding_t::bound`. The only change in the code that makes those four assertions not fail is the definition of the copy assignment operator without template parameters (the definition of this `operator=` in the MWE below has template parameters).

```
arrangement_collection& operator= (const arrangement_collection& ac) noexcept
{
    m_num_nodes = ac.m_num_nodes;
    return *this;
}
```

Without the template parameters, however, I get the following warning that I don't understand:

```
warning: implicitly-declared ‘constexpr arrangement_collection<free_tree, bounding_t::bound>::arrangement_collection(const arrangement_collection<free_tree, bounding_t::bound>&)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy]
../untitled2/main.cpp: In function ‘arrangement_collection<free_tree, bounding_t::bound> proxy_copy()’:
../untitled2/main.cpp:232:29: warning: implicitly-declared ‘constexpr arrangement_collection<free_tree, bounding_t::bound>::arrangement_collection(const arrangement_collection<free_tree, bounding_t::bound>&)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy]
  232 |         const auto ac2 = ac.first;
      |                             ^~~~~
../untitled2/main.cpp:122:33: note: because ‘arrangement_collection<free_tree, bounding_t::bound>’ has user-provided ‘arrangement_collection<tree_t, bound>& arrangement_collection<tree_t, bound>::operator=(const arrangement_collection<tree_t, bound>&) [with tree_t = free_tree; bounding_t bound = bounding_t::bound]’
  122 |         arrangement_collection& operator= (const arrangement_collection& ac) noexcept
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~
```

I'm using `g++ (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 11.1.0` and warning flags `-Wall -W`.

## Question

How can I define the copy/move constructors/assignment operators of this class template so that all assertions succeed without warnings?

## Minimal Working Example

The code below contains the class definition, has a few assertions at the end (with `std::is_constructible_v<>` and many others), and a little `main()` procedure illustrating a use case.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <utility>

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct free_tree {
    uint64_t get_num_nodes() const noexcept { return 10; }
    free_tree() noexcept = default;
    free_tree(uint64_t) noexcept { }
    free_tree(const free_tree&) noexcept = default;
    free_tree(free_tree&&) noexcept = default;
    free_tree& operator= (const free_tree&) noexcept = default;
    free_tree& operator= (free_tree&&) noexcept = default;
};
struct rooted_tree {
    uint64_t get_num_nodes() const noexcept { return 10; }
    rooted_tree() noexcept = default;
    rooted_tree(uint64_t) noexcept { }
    rooted_tree(const rooted_tree&) noexcept = default;
    rooted_tree(rooted_tree&&) noexcept = default;
    rooted_tree& operator= (const rooted_tree&) noexcept = default;
    rooted_tree& operator= (rooted_tree&&) noexcept = default;
};

enum class bounding_t { bound, unbound };
template<bounding_t b>
static constexpr bool is_collection_bound = b == bounding_t::bound;
template<bounding_t b>
static constexpr bool is_collection_unbound = b == bounding_t::unbound;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename tree_t>
struct base_tree {
    base_tree(const tree_t& t) noexcept : m_t(t) { }
    ~base_tree() noexcept = default;
    base_tree(const base_tree& bt) noexcept = default;
    base_tree(base_tree&& bt) noexcept = default;
    base_tree& operator= (const base_tree& bt) noexcept = default;
    base_tree& operator= (base_tree&& bt) noexcept = default;

    const tree_t& m_t;
};

template <typename tree_t>
struct base_empty {
    base_empty() noexcept = default;
    ~base_empty() noexcept = default;
    base_empty(const base_empty& bt) noexcept = default;
    base_empty(base_empty&& bt) noexcept = default;
    base_empty& operator= (const base_empty& bt) noexcept = default;
    base_empty& operator= (base_empty&& bt) noexcept = default;
};

template <typename tree_t, bounding_t bound>
using base_impl =
    std::conditional_t<is_collection_bound<bound>,
                       base_tree<tree_t>,
                       base_empty<tree_t>>;

template <typename tree_t, bounding_t bound>
class arrangement_collection : public base_impl<tree_t, bound> {
public:
    template <typename t, bounding_t b> using ac = arrangement_collection<t, b>;

public:
    // ------------------
    // BASIC CONSTRUCTORS

    // when bound == bounding_t::bound
    template <bounding_t cb = bound, std::enable_if_t<is_collection_bound<cb>, bool> = true>
    arrangement_collection(const tree_t& t) noexcept
        : base_tree<tree_t>(t), m_num_nodes(t.get_num_nodes())
    { }

    // when bound == bounding_t::unbound
    template <bounding_t cb = bound, std::enable_if_t<is_collection_unbound<cb>, bool> = true>
    arrangement_collection(uint64_t n) noexcept
        : base_empty<tree_t>(), m_num_nodes(n)
    { }

    // -----------------
    // COPY CONSTRUCTORS

    // for bound == bounding_t::bound
    template <
        typename otree_t,
        bounding_t cb = bound, std::enable_if_t<is_collection_bound<cb>, bool> = true
    >
    arrangement_collection(const arrangement_collection<otree_t, bounding_t::bound>& ac) noexcept
        : base_tree<tree_t>(ac.m_t), m_num_nodes(ac.m_num_nodes)
    { }

    template <
        typename otree_t,
        bounding_t cb = bound, std::enable_if_t<is_collection_bound<cb>, bool> = true
    >
    arrangement_collection(const tree_t& t, const arrangement_collection<otree_t, bounding_t::unbound>& ac) noexcept
        : base_tree<tree_t>(t), m_num_nodes(ac.m_num_nodes)
    { }

    // for bound == bounding_t::unbound
    template <
        typename otree_t, bounding_t b,
        bounding_t cb = bound, std::enable_if_t<is_collection_unbound<cb>, bool> = true
    >
    arrangement_collection(const arrangement_collection<otree_t, b>& ac) noexcept
        : base_empty<tree_t>(), m_num_nodes(ac.m_num_nodes)
    { }

    // -------------------------
    // COPY ASSIGNMENT OPERATORS

    arrangement_collection& operator= (const arrangement_collection& ac) noexcept
    {
        m_num_nodes = ac.m_num_nodes;
        return *this;
    }

    void set_num_nodes(uint64_t n) noexcept { m_num_nodes = n; }

public:
    uint64_t m_num_nodes;
};

namespace static_assertions {

typedef arrangement_collection<free_tree, bounding_t::bound> ac_free_linear_bound;
typedef arrangement_collection<free_tree, bounding_t::unbound> ac_free_linear_unbound;

typedef arrangement_collection<rooted_tree, bounding_t::bound> ac_rooted_linear_bound;
typedef arrangement_collection<rooted_tree, bounding_t::unbound> ac_rooted_linear_unbound;

static_assert(
        std::is_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_bound, const free_tree&>
and not std::is_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound, const free_tree&>
and     std::is_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound, const rooted_tree&>
//
and     std::is_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_bound, free_tree>
and not std::is_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound, free_tree>
and     std::is_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound, rooted_tree>
//
and     std::is_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_bound, const free_tree>
and not std::is_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound, const free_tree>
and     std::is_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound, const rooted_tree>
//
and     std::is_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_bound, free_tree&>
and not std::is_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound, free_tree&>
and     std::is_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound, rooted_tree&>
//
// These classes *can* be constructed from uint64_t since free_tree is
// constructible from uint64_t
and     std::is_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_bound, uint64_t&>
and     std::is_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound, uint64_t&>
and     std::is_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_bound, uint64_t>
and     std::is_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound, uint64_t>
);

static_assert(
    not std::is_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_unbound, const free_tree&>
and not std::is_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_unbound, const rooted_tree&>
and not std::is_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_unbound, const free_tree&>
and not std::is_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_unbound, const rooted_tree&>
and     std::is_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_unbound, uint64_t>
and     std::is_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_unbound, uint64_t>
);

static_assert(
    std::is_copy_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_bound>
and std::is_copy_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_unbound>
and std::is_copy_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound>
and std::is_copy_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_unbound>
);
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<ac_free_linear_bound>);
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound>);

static_assert(
    std::is_copy_assignable_v<ac_free_linear_unbound>
and std::is_copy_assignable_v<ac_rooted_linear_unbound>
);

static_assert(
    std::is_move_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_bound>
and std::is_move_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_unbound>
and std::is_move_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound>
and std::is_move_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_unbound>
);

static_assert(
    std::is_move_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_bound>
and std::is_move_constructible_v<ac_free_linear_unbound>
and std::is_move_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound>
and std::is_move_constructible_v<ac_rooted_linear_unbound>
);

static_assert(
    std::is_move_assignable_v<ac_free_linear_unbound>
and std::is_move_assignable_v<ac_rooted_linear_unbound>
);
static_assert(std::is_move_assignable_v<ac_free_linear_bound>);
static_assert(std::is_move_assignable_v<ac_rooted_linear_bound>);

} // -- namespace static_assertions

std::pair<
    arrangement_collection<free_tree,bounding_t::bound>,
    arrangement_collection<free_tree,bounding_t::unbound>
>
make_arrangement_collection() noexcept
{
    free_tree ft;
    arrangement_collection<free_tree,bounding_t::bound> acb(ft);
    acb.set_num_nodes(10);

    arrangement_collection<free_tree,bounding_t::unbound> acu(10);
    acu.set_num_nodes(10);
    return std::make_pair(std::move(acb), std::move(acu));
}

arrangement_collection<free_tree,bounding_t::bound>
proxy_copy() noexcept
{
    const auto ac = make_arrangement_collection();
    const auto ac2 = ac.first;
    return ac2;
}

arrangement_collection<free_tree,bounding_t::bound>
proxy_move() noexcept
{
    const auto ac = make_arrangement_collection();
    return std::move(ac.first);
}

int main() {
    const auto accopy = proxy_copy();
    const auto acmove = proxy_move();
}
```

## A comment on 'Minimal'

The original class template has three template parameters and twice as many lines of code.

The whole code provided is long because it contains the definition of a `main()` procedure, the two classes that  and the assertions, but the actual class template is small.

Comment: I copied the MWE and compiled it with both g++ (9.4.0) and clang++ (5.0.0) with `-std=c++17`. Compilation succeeded without any warning.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the compiler version and the warning flags, uh. Could you try with flags `-Wall -W` please? I'm using `g++ (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 11.1.0`.

Comment: With `-Wall` I see the warnings you mentioned above. The warnings, as mentioned by @Artyer below, can be resolved by declaring a copy constructor explictly in the `arrangement_collection` class: `arrangement_collection(const arrangement_collection&) = default;` But still, I don't see any assertion failed.

Comment: Clang analyzer (I'm using Qt Creator) gives the following warning: "using copy constructor but class has a trivial copy constructor but non trivial assign operator" in lines 238 and 246. What does it mean?

Comment: That `class has a trivial copy constructor` is because we just add a `default` copy constructor, and that `non trivial assign operator` is because we have explicitly declared `operator=` for `arrangement_collection`. Given that the `operator=` only assigns a public field `m_num_nodes`, my suggestion is to make the `operator=` also default. In other words, we change the `operator=` to `arrangement_collection& operator= (const arrangement_collection& ac) noexcept = default`. Then, I found that four assertions failed now.

Comment: OK, now I see why there is assertion failure. That the class `arrangement_collection` is not copy/move assignable is because its base class is not copy/move assignable. Which base class? It is `base_tree`. Why? Because its only filed `m_t` is a const reference, which is not mutable. Can we change `m_t` to a pointer because pointer can be changed?

Comment: The pointer would be a way to go, but aren't the base classes `base_tree` and `base_empty` copy/move assignable? I mean, the methods are defined and the compiler is fine with them. Oh, btw, I applied the changes suggested by [Artyer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71909235/12075306) and I got the actual code working.

Comment: Are the base classes base_tree and base_empty copy/move assignable? Nope for base_tree because a reference type is not copy/move assignable. For example, given `int b; int& a = b;`, that `int c; a = c` will be illegal. I guess that the code works is because only copy construction is used while copy assignment is not used?

Comment: You've made a really good point. I guess the code compiles and works because the base classes have their operators and constructors defined and `default`ed, in spite of one of them having a `const tree_t&` member. I don't have enough knowledge/expertise on C++ to answer more precisely.  Now, using the code in the post I wrote a little use case of copy assignment and the references are not updated; I expect the behaviour to be like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class currently doesn't have a copy constructor, since the copy constructor cannot be a template (and the ones you defined will never be used). Generating an implicitly-defined copy constructor is deprecated for types that have a user-defined copy assignment operator.

However, the default definition of the copy constructor does what you want (copying a `base_empty<tree_t>` has no overhead), so just `arrangement_collection(const arrangement_collection&) = default;` will work.

You can also rewrite this so the constructors are in `base_tree<tree_t>` and `base_empty<tree_t>`, so in `arrangement_collection` you can just inherit the constructors with `using base_impl<tree_t, bound>::base_impl`, avoiding all the `enable_if` SFINAE

Comment: I understood the first part (the defaulted constructor), but not the second. Could you elaborate, please? Thank you for your time and efforts.